# What is the difference between a iTunes ID and an Apple ID?

Tags: itunes, apple-id

I have an Apple ID, do I also need an iTunes ID to purchase music?

Answer (score 6):

There is no difference, Apple ID is the more general term and the one more commonly used nowadays.

Comment: As long as you have an Apple ID, you should be able to use the same ID for iTunes store and App Store

Comment: There is no difference. The same ID is used for iTunes, the App Store, iCloud, and a few other things.